# Is it possible to share my localhost with someone on a different network?

Tags: hosts, ngrok

I am working with a designer and I'd like them to have access to the interactions I've implemented on the site we're working on. However this time, I have 2 issues.  My localhost is configured to a subdomain: 
http://store.teststore:3000/ and we're on different networks.  Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: You can "host" your site locally and give them your IP address assuming the firewall on your machine does not block the port on which you are hosting.

Comment: I've used ngrok.io in the past for these issues. Basically it creates a proxy for you pointing to the port/location that you want, you can give him the proxy url and he should be able to access it (also allows others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngrok should work for you. Download and install it following these instructions here: https://ngrok.com/download. Documentation on how it is used can be found here https://ngrok.com/docs. Once installed running the below command should work for you (depending on the hosting environment):

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite store.teststore:3000
```

You will need to give the URL generated by ngrok and displayed in the cmd prompt to the designer.

**Update: Handling absolute redirects**

Based on your comment it sounds like, after login, your site does an absolute redirect (the full URL is specified). If it is possible I would change your code to do a relative redirect where the domain is omitted. You could also make your root domain configurable in the absolute redirect and configure it to be the ngrok domain provided for now. Lastly, you could attempt to configure your DNS with a CNAME record following ngroks [Tunnels to custom domains](https://ngrok.com/docs#custom-domains) documentation. This last option, however, requires a paid for ngrok subscription.

Comment: thanks jason! This worked perfectly but I just realized that after logging in from store.teststore:3000, it redirects to store.teststore:3000/account.  Is there anyway of doing this with ngrok or is this much more complex?

Comment: @RohimL Your welcome! I updated my answer to address your additional question.

Answer (score 0):

Install ngrok if you haven't yet and CD into your project directory and invoke ngrok. **Note** Your application must be running locally on the same port number ngrok will be running.